# "use chrome headless mode" in chrome driver config in jmeter not working

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, driver, config

Hello I tried to run chrome headless browser in jmeter but its not working.
Please check screenshot for error log[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgLj0.png).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using the following software:

- [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)
- [ChromeDriver 2.43.600210](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/) (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a)
- [WebDriver Sampler 3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.0)

[image]

So my expectation is that your setup is somehow corrupt, i.e. you have Selenium Java dependencies not matching the WebDriver Sampler version. Consider reinstalling clean JMeter 5.0 and get the latest WebDriver Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: How can we run the selenium script without opening the chrome instances using chrome driver ?? I want to execute the script using the Linux server and there is no chrome available on the server-side. So how can I achieved that ??